# Pop-up message on macOS programming

Tags: xcode, macos, popup

Like using UIAlertView on iOS. There should be a similar solution for creating a pop-up message on macOS. Tried to search but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

The class you're looking for is `NSAlert`. Information on this class can be found in its [class reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And here is an example of its usage:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];

[alert setMessageText:@"Some awesome message text"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[alert runModal];
```

Comment: If you app is using ARC (automatic reference counting) you don't need to call autorelease.  ARC mode is the norm for most iOS and Mac OSX apps now.